# Android Custom View preview in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-custom-view

I am developing a custom view & I want it displays like Google Ads view below. My view doesn't contain any text view but I still want it to have a preview like that.

Can anyone support me to a solution? Thank you!!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "tools" namespace might be able to help you here. You can add it with a line like:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

in your root layout. Things like tools:text will show up in the preview, but not when the app is run. So the following view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        tools:text="Preview Text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

will show a TextView with "Preview Text" visible in the preview, but it is actually View.GONE and has no text when run.

Comment: I think this is a nice trick to achieve the result. By the way, do you think that Google View does the same? Thank you!!

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't used a Google View in this way before. But I figured worst case scenario you can add a TextView to your layout in the same place as your Google View but with android:visibility="gone" so it doesn't show when you run the code, but you can make it appear in the preview with tools.